# Auto Bootstrap Modal / Dialog Box after Page load is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-modal

I am using Django Web Framework. And trying to put Dialog box / Bootstrap modal.

After putting Bootstrap Modal my other element of Page is not working.

I might be something in my Head Section.

Following is my Modal code which is not working.

```
<!-- ======= Modal ======= -->
  <div class="bs-example">
      <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                      <h5 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h5>
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                      <p>Do you want to save changes to this document before closing?</p>
                      <p class="text-secondary"><small>If you don't save, your changes will be lost.</small></p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>   <!-- ======= End of Modal ======= -->
```

Above Bootstrap Modal required some compile Js file as below in under head tag

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">

  <title>Weeffective | Homepage</title>

<!-- Vendor JS Files -->
  <script src="static/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="static/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="static/vendor/jquery.easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
  <script src="static/vendor/php-email-form/validate.js"></script>
  <script src="static/vendor/isotope-layout/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
  <script src="static/vendor/venobox/venobox.min.js"></script>
  <script src="static/vendor/owl.carousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="static/vendor/aos/aos.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Template Main JS File -->
  <script src="static/js/main.js"></script>



  <!-- Modal File -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> -->

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myModal").modal('show');
    });
  </script>
<style>
      .bs-example{
        margin: 20px;
      }
  </style>
</head>
```

Then my Modal works fine but my JS files does not work.

My Console give me following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(..).owlCaraousel is not a function
>   at main.js

Thank you for your time and consideration

Edit main.js file:

```
/**
* Template Name: Scaffold - v2.0.0
* Template URL: https://bootstrapmade.com/scaffold-bootstrap-metro-style-template/
* Author: BootstrapMade.com
* License: https://bootstrapmade.com/license/
*/

!(function($) {
  "use strict";

  // Smooth scroll for the navigation menu and links with .scrollto classes
  $(document).on('click', '.nav-menu a, .mobile-nav a, .scrollto', function(e) {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var target = $(this.hash);
      if (target.length) {

        var scrollto = target.offset().top;

        if ($('#header').length) {
          scrollto -= $('#header').outerHeight() - 2

        }

        if ($(this).attr("href") == '#header') {
          scrollto = 0;
        }

        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: scrollto
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');

        if ($(this).parents('.nav-menu, .mobile-nav').length) {
          $('.nav-menu .active, .mobile-nav .active').removeClass('active');
          $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
        }

        if ($('body').hasClass('mobile-nav-active')) {
          $('body').removeClass('mobile-nav-active');
          $('.mobile-nav-toggle i').toggleClass('icofont-navigation-menu icofont-close');
          $('.mobile-nav-overly').fadeOut();
        }
        return false;
      }
    }
  });

  // Mobile Navigation
  if ($('.nav-menu').length) {
    var $mobile_nav = $('.nav-menu').clone().prop({
      class: 'mobile-nav d-lg-none'
    });
    $('body').append($mobile_nav);
    $('body').prepend('<button type="button" class="mobile-nav-toggle d-lg-none"><i class="icofont-navigation-menu"></i></button>');
    $('body').append('<div class="mobile-nav-overly"></div>');

    $(document).on('click', '.mobile-nav-toggle', function(e) {
      $('body').toggleClass('mobile-nav-active');
      $('.mobile-nav-toggle i').toggleClass('icofont-navigation-menu icofont-close');
      $('.mobile-nav-overly').toggle();
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.mobile-nav .drop-down > a', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
      $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
    });

    $(document).click(function(e) {
      var container = $(".mobile-nav, .mobile-nav-toggle");
      if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        if ($('body').hasClass('mobile-nav-active')) {
          $('body').removeClass('mobile-nav-active');
          $('.mobile-nav-toggle i').toggleClass('icofont-navigation-menu icofont-close');
          $('.mobile-nav-overly').fadeOut();
        }
      }
    });
  } else if ($(".mobile-nav, .mobile-nav-toggle").length) {
    $(".mobile-nav, .mobile-nav-toggle").hide();
  }

  // Navigation active state on scroll
  var nav_sections = $('section');
  var main_nav = $('.nav-menu, #mobile-nav');

  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var cur_pos = $(this).scrollTop() + 80;

    nav_sections.each(function() {
      var top = $(this).offset().top,
        bottom = top + $(this).outerHeight();

      if (cur_pos >= top && cur_pos <= bottom) {
        if (cur_pos <= bottom) {
          main_nav.find('li').removeClass('active');
        }
        main_nav.find('a[href="#' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]').parent('li').addClass('active');
      }
    });
  });

  // Toggle .header-scrolled class to #header when page is scrolled
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
      $('#header').addClass('header-scrolled');
    } else {
      $('#header').removeClass('header-scrolled');
    }
  });

  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
    $('#header').addClass('header-scrolled');
  }

  // Back to top button
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
      $('.back-to-top').fadeIn('slow');
    } else {
      $('.back-to-top').fadeOut('slow');
    }
  });

  $('.back-to-top').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo', function() {
      $(".nav-menu ul:first li:first").addClass('active');
    });

    return false;
  });

  // Porfolio isotope and filter
  $(window).on('load', function() {
    var portfolioIsotope = $('.portfolio-container').isotope({
      itemSelector: '.portfolio-item',
      layoutMode: 'fitRows'
    });

    $('#portfolio-flters li').on('click', function() {
      $("#portfolio-flters li").removeClass('filter-active');
      $(this).addClass('filter-active');

      portfolioIsotope.isotope({
        filter: $(this).data('filter')
      });
    });

    // Initiate venobox (lightbox feature used in portofilo)
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.venobox').venobox();
    });
  });

  // Testimonials carousel (uses the Owl Carousel library)
  $(".testimonials-carousel").owlCarousel({
    autoplay: true,
    dots: true,
    loop: true,
    responsive: {
      0: {
        items: 1
      },
      768: {
        items: 2
      },
      900: {
        items: 3
      }
    }
  });

  // Portfolio details carousel
  $(".portfolio-details-carousel").owlCarousel({
    autoplay: true,
    dots: true,
    loop: true,
    items: 1
  });

  // Initi AOS
  AOS.init({
    duration: 800
  });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I can see that you are loading `owl.carousel.min.css`. But can you confirm if you are actually loading `owl.carousel.min.js` file?

Comment: After `adding owl.carousel.min.js` file i am getting Uncaught TypeError: $(..).owlCaraousel is not a function

Comment: can you paste the snippet of how you are calling that function? Also, make sure you are spelling it right `$('#...'). owlCarousel()`and not `owlCaraousel`

Comment: @SpiritOfDragon Added

Comment: See now i able to get Bootstrap Modal but other element of page is not coming except navbar.

Comment: without any code snippet, I would not be able to help. Update the code where you are facing the issue.

Comment: @SpiritOfDragon I have added whole main.js file Question.

Comment: And now bootstrap Modal is coming after page load. But other element of page is not coming.